# jQuery validation plugin - numbers only, min & max length - space issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validation (**[PLUGIN URL](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/)**) plugin for most of my form validation:

I have following example (**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/7BqxN/19/)**):

**FORM:**

```
 <form class="form" id="feedback-form" method="post" action="#">


    <label for="phone">Contact number:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="phone" name="phone" class="required">
    <br class="clr">

    <div class="form-buttons">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" >
    </div>
    <br class="clr">
    <br /><br />

</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#feedback-form").validate({
    rules: {

        phone: {
            number: true, // as space is not a number it will return an error
            minlength: 6, // will count space 
            maxlength: 9
        }

    }

});
```

**I have two issues, both relating to space usage.**

- min & max length will count space as an character
- if `number = true` and space is used, it will return error as space is not a number

**Is there any workaround this? Have any of you bumped in on the same problem?** Please note I want to keep allowing to type in space (for readability).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a beforeValidation callback to send the value without spaces, take a look here: [Jquery Validator before Validation callback](http://desertrose.posterous.com/jquery-validator-before-validation-callback), it seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: This will stop user from entering space. Not a perfect solution. As I would like to keep space separating for readability, but not include space in character count.

Answer (score 0):

a very smiple solution is :

replace the type of the phone input as the following :

```
<input id="phone" type="number" maxlength="10" size="2" max="99" style="width:36px;" required />
```

and you would never have issues with spaces and stuff, just used that in my code !

enjoy